# Recursive search through the folder tree (algorithm and JavaScript realization)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

My goal is to create optimal algorithm for recursive search through the folder tree with handling **all directories of each "level"**. And realize it on JavaScript.

I wrote this code sample:

```
function deepSearch ( dirPath, startPoint, searchRequest ) {
    var listDir = getListDir(dirPath), // pseudo function for getting dir's content
        currentElemsAmount = listDir.length, // amount of file objects
        i = startPoint;

    deepSearch.scale = deepSearch.scale || [];
    deepSearch.result = deepSearch.result || [];
    deepSearch.request = deepSearch.request || searchRequest || '';

    for ( ; i < currentElemsAmount; i += 1 ) {
        if ( isFile(listDir[i]) ) { // pseudo function to detect if file object is essentially file
            // compare some file attributes with search request
            if ( listDir[i].name.match(RegExp(searchRequest)) ) { // pseudo code
                deepSearch.result.push(listDir[i]);
            }
        } else {
            deepSearch.scale.push(i);
            deepSearch(newDirPath, 0); // pseudo code
        }
    }

    if ( deepSearch.scale.length ) {
        deepSearch(goBackInPathOnOneLevel(dirPath, deepSearch.scale.pop() + 1)); // pseudo function to go up in tree
    } else {
        return deepSearch.result;
    }
}
```

How can I improve it? Is it possible to make it better? What's about alternative approaches and solutions? Is it correct at all?

Would be highly appreciated your opinions.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using it in a node.js env? Because you don't have access to the filesystem through the browser.

Comment: Yes, I use it in a Node.js env.

Comment: If the code is already working, you probably should better ask at [codereview.SE]

Comment: Why don't you start to replace the pseudo-functions with the actual functions that [Nodes File System Module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) provides.